# JMeter : Run all tests in a file

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I have around 4 files named:

```
Test_1.csv
Test_2.csv
...
```

Each line in each test file has the following format:

```
method;request
```

Where, `method` is the URL that I call and `request` is the request I make to it. Everything is configured to pick up these values and form URLs.

However, first `Test_1.csv` must run, then `Test_2.csv` must run and so on. To do that, I have created 5 thread groups in the following hierarchy:

```
Test Plan
 |
 +- Step 1
     |
     +- HTTP request
     +- CSV Data Set Config <- Reads from Test_1.csv
     +- Uniform Random Timer
 +- Step 2
     |
     +- HTTP request
     +- CSV Data Set Config <- Reads from Test_2.csv
     +- Uniform Random Timer
```

And I have also selected the `Run thread groups consecutively` option in my test plan. Each thread group is configured for 20 threads. Now, what I want it to do is that, Step 1 should run each and every test in `Test_1.csv`, then Step 2 should execute and run each and every line in `Test_2.csv`. However, what is happening is that, Step 1 runs the first 20 lines from `Test_1.csv` and then Step 2 starts, runs 20 tests and continues. Then, after all steps are done, Step 1 runs again and runs the very same 20 lines from `Test1.csv`. I want it to just run once, loop through all the lines in the test file and then quit and hand over control to the next thread.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following schema:

```
Test Plan
    Thread Group #1
    Number of Threads: N
        . . .
        While Controller
        Condition: ${__javaScript("${request}"!="<EOF>",)} - until the EOF
            CSV Data Set Config
            Filename: [path to your file with test-data] - Test_1.csv in this case
            Variable Names: method,request
            HTTP Request
                Uniform Random Timer
            . . .           
    Thread Group #2
        . . .
        [same for Test_2.csv]
    Thread Group #3
        . . .
        [same for Test_3.csv]
```

Comment: Just a thought: This While Loop solves the reading till EOF issue but would it not make more sense to have the requests all in one Thread Group? Then they're executed in series by default and control of threads is easy. I'm not sure if this is a 'good' way to structure a test but it meets the OP's desired way of running things, for better or worse...

Comment: Hi Oliver. Thank you for this note. Think you are right, but seems to me I can remember issue with While Controller usage - as well it can be in previous versions, or even only my "local" issue: samplers AFTER While Controller on the same level weren't executed, so the schema you've described wasn't operative, and my code above is simply workaround for this. If that's already fixed or never was an issue so your approach is certainly better.

Answer (score 0):

jMeter Plugins' [ParameterizedController](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ParameterizedController) can help you call parts of your test plan like you call functions in a regular programming language. More importantly, you can parametrise those calls with variables.